# Can't reindex magento 1.7.0.2 stuck on "processing"

Tags: git, magento

7 out of 9 of my magento indexes are stuck on "processing", and I need to reindex them to get my site showing correctly.

I access my var/locks via ftp and delete the two files that are in there, but when I refresh the index page, they just reapper (index_process_3.lock) and (index_process_5.lock).

Funnily index 3 and 5 are the only ones that are actually ready, all the other locks that don't appear are the ones stuck on processing.

Any clues on how to go about this?

Comment: do you have any errors logged in `var/log`? assuming error logging is enabled from system->developer->log settings

Comment: Could be anything from a disabled extension, to running out of memory. see @Marius answer to get to the right direction or see your php error_log

Answer (score 3):

Check the table index_process, delete the locks from there and also from var/locks and try again. Also on 1.7.0.2 there is a bug when indexing, it creates some exclusive locks in the database on some tables and you can't use them, you can find a fix in the latest Enterprise version.
I would recommend indexing from php cli > shell/indexer.php

Comment: I have a theme that is not compatible with versions higher than 1.7.0.2 and unfortunately I cannot get shell access as I'm hosted at pagodabox. What do I look for in the index_process table?

Comment: 1.7.0.2 is the latest Community version so the theme should be compatible with the latest Enterprise version (but this one costs a lot). In the index_process table you should look for processes that have status "working" and change them to "pending" - in the admin area under indexing you actually see the status from this table, not var/locks

Answer (score 2):

Open your system.log.
If you see *Warning: fwrite() errors* then check permissions on [Magento_installation]/var/locks

enter with SSH on **var** dir and run :

```
chown apache locks
```

Where apache is the server user

If doesn´t works other solution less secure :

```
chmod -R 777 locks
```