# upgraded magento enterprise from 1.12.0.2 to magento 1.13.0.2 Catalog Category/Product Index never ends

Tags: magento

I have upgraded magento enterprise from 1.12.0.2 to magento 1.13.0.2 successfully. All our local modification are wprking fine now.

I am facing issue with magento indexing. I have run full indexer all indexing process completed but  Catalog Category/Product Index  still in process. I tried to remove all locaks file still it is in process state and it is running from last 26 days.

Please help as we need to go live :
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/578822/

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion

Comment: Look at my answear here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145393/cant-reindex-magento-1-7-0-2-stuck-on-processing/18147859#comment26580582_18147859

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure it's still running or is it just telling you it's running?  Try looking at your MySQL processes with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and see if there are any queries running on the `product_flat` or `category_flat` tables.

Try running the indexer through shell, `php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product`.  Are there any errors being output to the console?  Have you checked `system.log` and `exception.log`?

Try running the [db repair tool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool) on your store to fix any broken tables.

Comment: i have already disabled flat table for both product and category, and apache and mysql server restarted many time,dekleted all index locks